# Designing implementations with minimal change

Tags: design-patterns

**Theoretical discussion**

I have a code base with an interface and an implementation . Lets call the implementation as implA spread across multiple .h and .cpp files . Now I am required to have an alternate implementation of the interface . However 98% of the code is same . Now multiple options exists .

option 1 ) make changes in implA and change code based on a flag and under some flag implB related changes come into affect . Its bad because  my code will have a lot of if and else and things will be cluttered and hard to understand .

option 2)  I have   to copy paste entire implA to implB and then make changes in implB. This way   both interfaces are seperate but then tere is a design principle . Dont repeat yourself  . If tomorrow there is a bug in implA , i will have to remember and change part in implB area as well .

option 3) Take out common areas into some   class . use that as aggregation in these 2 impls. This seems plausible and  OK but then i am changing implA as well when there is no need to touch implA . I should not be touching files and implementations which are not required to be changed

please suggest

Comment: Another option: `implB` is a subclass of `implA`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - Sounds like Option 3 where you don't want to change implA. You shouldn't couple code like that and we all know what if/else code tends to grow to.

Option 2 - I don't think this would do you any good, because as you said, every fix or feature will have to be implemented in 2 places.

Option 3 - If you could use the abstract parts of implA to build implB that would seem like a faster way to write implB, but if implA was not abstracted enough to be used, then i guess putting a little work into implA would make double the benefits as it will be used for implB as well.

Option 3 sounds like the most robust and scalable option.